# Несколько страниц на html с загрузкой только блока контента

Tags: html, css

Хочу сделать (точнее перенести) простенький сайт-визитку только на html и css (без использования движков).

Каждая страница содержит стандартную шапку и футер, а контент меняется на каждой странице.

Мне придется заново писать весь код для каждой страницы или возможно использовать что-то вроде шаблона в котором будет меняться только содержимое (без использования скриптов)?

Comment: А чем скрипты не угодили-то? Вообще есть генераторы статических сайтов, идеально подходящие для подобных задач, но если они попадают под определение «скрипты», тогда можно что-нибудь на фреймах (или на js, если он допустим) накостылять

Comment: Можно использовать расширение php чтобы инклюдить шапку с подвалом, а если принципиально использование именно html, можно воспользоваться шаблонизатором, например pug.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. В вопросе я наверное слишком категоричен 
 к скриптам, но это от недостатка знаний. Не знал о существовании Генераторов статических сайтов (это почти то, что мне нужно) и Шаблонизаторов (скорее всего это именно то что нужно).
Я получил ответ. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Так-то шаблонизаторы используются внутри генераторов и скриптов)

Comment: я это понял, поэтому и писал что в вопросе был слишком категоричен к скриптам, но видимо это единственный путь - немного подтянуть знания в этом вопросе.